# Alexa skills kit integration with locally hosted service gives error

Tags: ssl-certificate, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to integrate Alexa with my locally hosted service. I am trying to hit my URL
https://www.myurl.com:443/somepath

I am generating a self signed certificate for the domain "myurl.com."

However, when I test it in the service simulator I get the response 
"The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid."

The error is "Parse error on line 1: The remote endpoint".
Could someone tell me how exactly I could integrate Alexa with the URL stated above?

Comment: Does it work with other tools? Like Postman, curl? For testing you can use something like the Bespoken tools or ngrok.

Comment: Yes, it works with curl. I have been using this for a long time.